# Magento 2: Apply discount calculation on total item price instead of single item price

Tags: php, magento

is it possible in the current version of Magento 2 to apply the discount calculation on the cart total price ((Qty in cart * Price) - Discount) instead of the single item price. ((Price - Discount) * Qty)

We use a lot of discount rules. Sometimes multiple rules. The current behavior of magento causes rounding errors with the currently used accounting software.

Is there a way to change the calculation behavior of Magento?

Thanks in advance.